# How to correctly override "jQuery Unobtrusive Validation" to work for css bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 base project in which I use css bootstrap for designing my pages.

To work property with css bootstrap. I want to be able to override the default behavior of the `errorElement`, `errorClass`, `highlight`,`unhighlight` and `errorPlacement` properties/functions.

This is what I have tried

First, I included the packages in the following order

1. jQuery (v3.1.1)
2. jquery.validate.min.js (v1.15.0)
3. My settings where I override the default behavior (Code below)
4. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js (v3.2.3)

This is my first attempt into overriding the package

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

        var elm = $(element);

        console.log('errorPlacement was called');

        if (elm.parent('.input-group').length) {
            console.log('parent');
            console.log(elm.parent());
            error.insertAfter(elm.parent());
        }
        else if (elm.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || elm.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.appendTo(elm.closest(':not(input, label, .checkbox, .radio)').first());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(elm);
        }
    }
});
```

However, the above code will never call the `errorPlacement` function, other than that everything else works as expected. But since the `errorPlacement` method is not being called, the error is being placed in a different place.

Then I changed the above code to this (overriding both jQuery validation and the Unobtrusive)

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        console.log('highlight was called');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        console.log('highlight was called');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { }
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.options = {
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

        var elm = $(element);
        console.log('errorPlacement was called');

        if (elm.parent('.input-group').length || elm.parent('.input-group-custom').length) {
            console.log('parent');
            console.log(elm.parent());
            error.insertAfter(elm.parent());
        }
        else if (elm.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || elm.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.appendTo(elm.closest(':not(input, label, .checkbox, .radio)').first());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(elm);
        }
    }
};
```

Now, the function `errorPlacement` is being called. But, the error is being inserted multiple time. Somehow the code the removes the error message is not being called now.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: That didn't work?  Did you place `$.validator.setDefaults()` inside or outside of your document ready function?

Comment: It did not work. Yes I placed it inside `$(function () {....});` block. To make sure I am clear on what did not work is that the function `errorPlacement` was not called. but the rest worked fine.

Comment: That's your problem.  Thanks to the Unobtrusive plugin, your `.setDefaults()` is being called *after* the `.validate()` initialization.  The only way to force `.setDefaults()` to get called before `.validate()` in this case is to place it outside of your document ready.

Comment: It's not likely that only some of `.setDefaults()` is being ignored.

Comment: is there a workaround?

Comment: Workaround for what?  Read previous comment:  *"The only way to force `.setDefaults()` to get called before `.validate()` in this case (with unobtrusive) is to **place it (setDefaults) outside of your document ready**."*

Answer (score 16):

This is how I override jQuery Unobtrusive Validation to work with Bootstrap 4.

```js
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: "",
    validClass: "",
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass("is-invalid").removeClass("is-valid");
        $(element.form).find('[data-valmsg-for="' + element.name + '"]').addClass("invalid-feedback");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass("is-valid").removeClass("is-invalid");
        $(element.form).find('[data-valmsg-for="' + element.name + '"]').removeClass("invalid-feedback");
    },
});
```

Copy and paste the code above into a new file. Name it `jquery.validate.overrides.js`.

Edit BundleConfig.cs. Find the bundle `jqueryval`. Add path to new file at the end.

```cs
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.overrides.js"
));
```

To use in a view:

```cs
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "First name", type = "text" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
</div>
```

Comment: This is great. One issue i've found though is that if you get past client validation and server-side validation fails then the page doesn't add the bootstrap classes. Did you find a way to solve that?

Comment: I also have the same problem as Dave,  only works for client side, server side overrides the class with the standard 'input-validation-error'.